# `dplyr::select` without reordering columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for an easy, concise way to use `dplyr::select` without rearranging columns.

Consider this dataset:

```r
library(tidyverse)
head(msleep)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 11
#>   name    genus vore  order conservation sleep_total sleep_rem sleep_cycle awake
#>   <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Cheetah Acin… carni Carn… lc                  12.1      NA        NA      11.9
#> 2 Owl mo… Aotus omni  Prim… <NA>                17         1.8      NA       7  
#> 3 Mounta… Aplo… herbi Rode… nt                  14.4       2.4      NA       9.6
#> 4 Greate… Blar… omni  Sori… lc                  14.9       2.3       0.133   9.1
#> 5 Cow     Bos   herbi Arti… domesticated         4         0.7       0.667  20  
#> 6 Three-… Brad… herbi Pilo… <NA>                14.4       2.2       0.767   9.6
#> # … with 2 more variables: brainwt <dbl>, bodywt <dbl>
```

If I select `vore`, `genus` and `name`, the resulting dataframe is arranged in the order in which the columns were provided.

```r
msleep %>% select(vore, genus, name)
#> # A tibble: 83 × 3
#>    vore  genus       name                      
#>    <chr> <chr>       <chr>                     
#>  1 carni Acinonyx    Cheetah                   
#>  2 omni  Aotus       Owl monkey                
#>  3 herbi Aplodontia  Mountain beaver           
#>  4 omni  Blarina     Greater short-tailed shrew
#>  5 herbi Bos         Cow                       
#>  6 herbi Bradypus    Three-toed sloth          
#>  7 carni Callorhinus Northern fur seal         
#>  8 <NA>  Calomys     Vesper mouse              
#>  9 carni Canis       Dog                       
#> 10 herbi Capreolus   Roe deer                  
#> # … with 73 more rows
```

I would instead like to leave them in their default order: `name`, `genus`, then `vore`.

I have a solution (see below), but I do not like it because it is quite wordy, and not completely “tidyverse-esque”.
(I am teaching an intro to tidyverse course, and would like something that would not intimidate beginners.)

```r
msleep %>% 
  select(all_of(names(msleep)[names(msleep) %in% c("vore", "genus", "name")]))
#> # A tibble: 83 × 3
#>    name                       genus       vore 
#>    <chr>                      <chr>       <chr>
#>  1 Cheetah                    Acinonyx    carni
#>  2 Owl monkey                 Aotus       omni 
#>  3 Mountain beaver            Aplodontia  herbi
#>  4 Greater short-tailed shrew Blarina     omni 
#>  5 Cow                        Bos         herbi
#>  6 Three-toed sloth           Bradypus    herbi
#>  7 Northern fur seal          Callorhinus carni
#>  8 Vesper mouse               Calomys     <NA> 
#>  9 Dog                        Canis       carni
#> 10 Roe deer                   Capreolus   herbi
#> # … with 73 more rows
```

Is there such a thing? Thank you!

For context: In reality, we have a data frame with about 400 columns, from which we are selecting ~10-20 at a time to work with. The order of the columns in the original data frame is meaningful, but we don't want to have to labor over listing them in their correct order in the select statements. A very specific need, I'll admit.

<sup>Created on 2021-12-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Why not either `msleep %>% select(1:3)` or `msleep %>% select(name, genus, vore)`?

Comment: Yes, good point. I edited the question to provide a bit more context.

Comment: Yes! This is indeed the most beginner-friendly solution. Will probably end up using it. I guess it can't be the accepted answer since it technically isn't "`dplyr::select` without reordering columns"

Comment: @Adam could you include the `relocate` option in your current answer? I'll then mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the power of `eval_select()` to create a function to select and sort the columns.

```r
library(dplyr)

select_in_order <- function(data, ...) {
  ordered_cols <- sort(tidyselect::eval_select(expr(c(...)), data))
  select(data, ordered_cols)
}
```

So now this will do what you are asking. The benefit is that it will be "full feature" to what you are used to being able to enter into a `select()` statement.

```r
# library(ggplot2) # msleep is in ggplot2

msleep %>%
  select_in_order(vore, genus, name)

# this will work as well
msleep %>%
  select_in_order(starts_with("sleep"), vore, name:genus)
```

---

**EDIT**

As another option, simply use `relocate()` after your `select()` statement. This alternative approach accomplishes your end goal of keeping the columns in order in a way that is easy to understand by a beginner.

```r
msleep %>%
  select(vore, genus, name) %>%
  relocate(any_of(names(msleep)))
```

Comment: This is very elegant! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We could use `match` with `sort`

```
library(dplyr)
msleep %>%
    select(sort(match(c("vore", "genus", "name"), names(.))))
```

EDIT: Based on the OP's comments

Comment: Indeed this looks a lot more friendly! But it does not quite work for me though. Seems to needs a `sort`. So:
`msleep %>%
  select(sort(match(c("vore", "genus", "name"), names(.))))`.

Comment: @KeneDavidNwosu why do you need a `sort`.  I thought you wanted to get the columns in the same order as in the `vector` you passed.

Comment: Ah no no. This is a special case where I want the vector order to be ignored, in favor of the original order of the variables in the dataframe.

Comment: @KeneDavidNwosu suppose your vector is `nm1` `msleep %>% select(all_of(nm1[match(nm1, names(.))]))`

Answer (score 3):

Update:
In case of providing a vector we could do as akrun suggests in the comments:

```
nm1 <- c("vore", "genus", "name"); pattern <- str_c(nm1, collapse="|")
```

Original answer:

You could first define a string with the search items

and then use `matches`

```
pattern <- c("vore|genus|name")

select(msleep, matches(pattern))
```

```
   name                       genus       vore 
   <chr>                      <chr>       <chr>
 1 Cheetah                    Acinonyx    carni
 2 Owl monkey                 Aotus       omni 
 3 Mountain beaver            Aplodontia  herbi
 4 Greater short-tailed shrew Blarina     omni 
 5 Cow                        Bos         herbi
 6 Three-toed sloth           Bradypus    herbi
 7 Northern fur seal          Callorhinus carni
 8 Vesper mouse               Calomys     NA   
 9 Dog                        Canis       carni
10 Roe deer                   Capreolus   herbi
```

Comment: If the OP is passing a vector, `nm1 <- c("vore", "genus", "name"); pattern <- str_c(nm1, collapse="|")` also, may need to consider the word boundary with `\\b`